# Error installing Garuda Linux

Tags: system-installation, garuda-linux

How to resolve this error? This is the first time I have downloaded Garuda Linux (based on Arch Linux). I have downloaded it from SourceForge redirected from the official page [Garuda Linux Download](https://garudalinux.org/downloads.html). I have downloaded the Dragonized Gaming version. This is the first time I am booting this and I don't know what went wrong.
[image]
After following @Michael Dorst's solution, I get the following error
[image]

I have allocated 53 GiB but I don't know why it says that the partition is full.

Comment: Having the same problem. Try doing `Garuda Assistant > Reinstall all packages`. That worked for me once - however I'm reinstalling again and this time that did not work for me.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the reply, Michael Dorst. Will try and let you know.

Comment: @MichaelDorst, could you please check the edit? It didn't solve the problem.

Comment: "it says that the partition is full." Show output of `df` AS WELL AS `df -i`. You can have space but no free inodes which generates the same error but looks confusing.

Comment: I didn't experience that. The packages installed fine for me. But this only worked for me the first time I tried, not the second, so maybe it was something else I did and forgot about that actually fixed the issue.